# Relational Database in Google Cloud Platform Free Tier

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a hard time understanding the product set for Google Cloud Platform. I have an App Engine application that I am trying to run inside the free quota.

I could do with access to a relational database. Is there one available to me in the free tier? It doesn't seem to be the case, but could I install one on a Google Compute Engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only database you can use in free quota is Google’s non-relational database called Datastore. Unfortunately none of the Google Cloud SQL instances have free quotas.